# How to GET/POST files in express.static()

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a little confused as to how Express serves files.

Currently I have a `/public` directory to hold client-side resources. I configure Express using

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It was my impression that anything in this directory was public, and that HTTP method urls defaulted `/public` as the root directory for access (unless otherwise routed manually by Express).

There is no problem using GET on any file in this directory (client-side scripts, images, ect. However, I get 404's when trying to POST files inside this directory. Do I need to manually route all POST requests ala

`app.post(route, callback)`

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connect, and therefore, Express, the static middleware only accepts `GET` requests. See [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js#L55).

If you are trying to overwrite files in the public with a POST, you'll want to create a separate route for that.

Comment: OK thank you for the link - I missed that. Didn't know if there was simply an Express setting to enable static `POST`ing

Answer (score 2):

Connect/Express' [`static` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) only [supports `GET` and `HEAD` method](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.8.5/lib/middleware/static.js#L55):

```
if ('GET' != req.method && 'HEAD' != req.method) return next();
```

So, yes, if you want to be able to `POST` to paths matching static files, you'll need to define the handler(s) yourself.

Comment: You beat me to it! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I find an easy way to post static

```
app.use(staticPath, function(req, res, next){
if ('POST' != req.method){
    next()
}else{
    req.method = 'GET'
    next()
}
})
app.use(staticPath, express.static('./static'))
```

It works well, haha